# How to assemble strings into an array when grouping?

Tags: sql, select, clickhouse

I need to realize query like this:

```
SELECT id, array(object) FROM Table GROUP BY id
```

I understand it doen't work

I need to convert

```
 id | object
id1 | aaa
id1 | bbb
id2 | ccc
id2 | ddd
```

in

```
id1 | [aaa, bbb]
id2 | [ccc, ddd]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ClickHouse, just do

```
SELECT id, groupArray(object) FROM Table GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LISTAGG function

```
SELECT id,LISTAGG(object,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) from Table
```

Documentation is :

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030